# Populating a dropdown based on the first dropdown selection using funcion on React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which gets a data from an API using axios. I've created a custom axios functional component to call which only work inside a function (it throws an Invalid hook call error when used on class).

I've searched several questions on this site but all seems to be using a class. So, is it possible to populate a second dropdown based on the selection?

PS. I'm using react-bootstrap. I tried to implement it but the second dropdown does not update.

Here is my code: (Please bear with the code. It's dirty )

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import Loader from '../Components/Loader';
import Err404 from '../Views/Err404';
import { GetRequest } from '../Hooks/GetRequest';

function Profile() {

    let divs = GetRequest('/divisions')
    let subs = GetRequest('/subjects')

    const [selectedDiv, setSelectedDiv] = useState("")
    const [selectedSub, setSelectedSub] = useState("")

    let content = null
    let subOptions = null
    let divOptions = null
    let subArr = null
    let subFilter = null
    let disabled = true


    if (divs.error || subs.error) {
        return (<Err404 />)
    }

    if (divs.loading || subs.loading) {
        content = <Loader />
    }

    if (divs.data && subs.data) {
        content = null

        divOptions =
            divs.data.map((div) => (
                <option key={div._id}>{div.name}</option>
            ))

        subArr =
            subs.data.map((sub) => (
                {
                    key: sub._id,
                    courseCode: sub.courseCode,
                    division: sub.division
                }
            ))

        subOptions =
            subArr.map((sub) => (
                <option key={sub.key}>{sub.courseCode}</option>
            ))
    }

    const handleDiv = (e) => {
        disabled = false
        setSelectedDiv(e.target.value);

        console.log("selDiv: ", selectedDiv)

        console.log("subArr: ", subArr)

        subFilter =
            subArr.filter((sub) => (
                sub.division === selectedDiv
            ))

        subOptions =
            subFilter.map((sub) => (
                <option key={sub.key}>{sub.courseCode}</option>
            ))


        console.log("subOps: ", subOptions, "\nsubfil: ", subFilter)

    }

    const handleSub = (e) => {
        console.log("selSub: ", e.target.value);
        setSelectedSub(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <Container fluid="sm" className="p-2">
            {content ? content :
                <Form>
                    <Row>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                                <Form.Label>Divison</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    as="select"
                                    onChange={(e) => handleDiv(e)}
                                    defaultValue="Choose ..."
                                >
                                    <option disabled>Choose ...</option>
                                    {divOptions}
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlSelect1">
                                <Form.Label>Subject</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control
                                    as="select"
                                    onChange={(e) => handleSub}
                                    defaultValue="Choose ..."
                                    disabled={disabled}
                                >
                                    <option disabled>Choose ...</option>
                                    {subOptions}
                                </Form.Control>
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Form>
            }

        </Container>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to make it work

```
const handleDiv = (e) => {
        disabled = false
        setSelectedDiv(e.target.value);
    }

if (subArr) {
console.log("selDiv: ", selectedDiv)

        console.log("subArr: ", subArr)

        subFilter =
            subArr.filter((sub) => (
                sub.division === selectedDiv
            ))

        subOptions =
            subFilter.map((sub) => (
                <option key={sub.key}>{sub.courseCode}</option>
            ))


        console.log("subOps: ", subOptions, "\nsubfil: ", subFilter)
}
```